# Can I add localizations to Trac when Babel was installed after Trac?

Tags: localization, trac, babeljs

I have a Trac installation running which was installed on a clean, new virtual server. Unfortunately, the idea to provide Trac in a localized version (German to be specific) came after Trac was up and running.

As far as I understand, I would have had to install Babel before installing Trac in order to provice the software in multiple languages. From http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracL10N :

> If you're only interested in using a localized version of Trac, then nothing more than a standard TracInstall is needed, provided you installed Babel before.

Is there any chance to provide a localization when Trac is already running? I was obviously able to install Babel, but I do not know what to do next.

Your help is gladly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most scenarios you'll need to reinstall Trac after installing Babel. This shouldn't cause you any concern, and should not affect your data (though follow the common advice of always making a backup before doing anything).

If you have installed Trac from the source, you can force the catalogs to compile using the command: `python setup.py compile_catalog -f`. However, that really should not be necessary and you should be able to just run `python setup.py install` again. If you installed using `easy_install`, executing `easy_install` again should be sufficient.

Edit: When using distribute/setuptool 0.6.29 or later, the locale data is not included in the egg. A fix will be applied for Trac 0.12.6/1.0.2/1.1.2 ([#11640](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11640)). In the meantime, one workaround is to use `pip` to install Trac.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind overview, @RjOllos ! Trac was installed using `easy_install`. Please excuse my ignorance concerning Python and `easy_install`: Would I have to run `easy_install trac`? I did so, but I am only being told that the most recent version is already installed. Also, I am sure that I have installed Babel, but would I have to install a language pack before running the reinstallation of trac?

Comment: You could try deleting the existing egg and then running `easy_install`. You shouldn't have to install any language packs. The translations are distributed with the Trac source code.

Comment: Deleting the existing egg and running  `easy_install` again did indeed seem to "re-install" Trac. The software is still up and running, but in the preferences, I still cannot switch languages (neither as admin, nor as user). Are there any temporary files, like a cache, which would have to be deleted?

Comment: It appears that the `locale` directory is not being included in the egg, for reasons I'm not sure of. Which Python and setuptools (or distribute) version are you using (`setuptools --version`)? The locale data was correctly install when I installed Trac using `pip` (`pip install trac`).

Comment: We've confirmed an issue with Trac and setuptools/distribute and one of the developers on the Trac project has provided a fix [#11640](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11640?). The easiest workaround is probably to just use `pip`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The `setuptools` command is not found on the server, but `easy_install --version` tells me that setuptools 3.4.4 is installed. `pip` is not installed as well, so I will make up for installing `pip`, reinstalling trac and let you know about the result. Thanks in advance, will also have a closer look at the ticket you've created.

Comment: Installed `pip` using `easy_install pip`, deleted the file `Trac-1.0.1-py2.7.egg` and reinstalled trac using `pip install trac`. A lot of stuff was downloaded, and instead of creating the single egg file again, two new folders `Trac-1.0.1-py2.7.egg-info` and `trac` were created. I found the MO files in `trac/locale/`. Trac is still working, but still no language except "default language" in the language dropdown of Trac's preferences. Am I using the new downloaded Trac installation, or am I still using the old one because of temporary files or so?

Comment: Update: Trac is not working flawlessly anymore, getting 500 errors randomly (pressing F5 on the same page multiple times does *sometimes* end up with a 500 error)

Comment: Update 2: I restarted the Apache webserver. Since then, everything's working: No more 500 errors, and multiple languages - awesome! :-) @RjOllos : Do you want to add a new answer to this topic with a recapitulation of our findings? If not, I will simply accept this answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the additional details about the distribute/setuptool defect, and the workaround. Thanks!